# Plotly Dash: Chained callbacks are working fine, but always throw ValueError. How to fix or silence?

Tags: pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a dataset that lists different jobs and what tools are need by date and location. Here is a tiny example of my df:

```
State,County,Job,Tool,Start,End
LA,Acadia,A,Hammer,2020-10-19,2020-11-02
LA,Acadia,A,Drill,2020-11-02,2020-12-02
LA,Acadia,B,Hammer,2020-11-28,2020-12-30
LA,Orleans,A,Hammer,2020-10-03,2020-11-02
LA,Orleans,A,Drill,2020-11-05,2020-12-02
LA,Orleans,B,Hammer,2020-12-03,2020-12-30
TX,Travis,A,Hammer,2020-10-19,2020-11-02
TX,Travis,A,Drill,2020-11-02,2020-12-02
TX,Travis,B,Hammer,2020-11-28,2020-12-30
TX,Brazoria,A,Hammer,2020-10-03,2020-11-02
TX,Brazoria,A,Drill,2020-11-05,2020-12-02
TX,Brazoria,B,Hammer,2020-12-03,2020-12-30
```

My dcc.Dropdowns and dcc.RadioItems are as follows:

```
        html.Div([
            html.Label("State:", style={'fontSize': 30, 'textAlign': 'center'}),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='state-dpdn',
                options=[{'label': s, 'value': s} for s in sorted(df.State.unique())],
                value='LA',
                clearable=False,
            )],
        html.Div([
            html.Label("County:", style={'fontSize': 30, 'textAlign': 'center'}),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='county-dpdn',
                options=[],
                value=[],
                clearable=False
            )],
        html.Div([
            html.Label("Job:", style={'fontSize': 30, 'textAlign': 'center'}),
            dcc.RadioItems(
                id='radio-buttons',
                options=[],
            ),
```

And here are my callbacks:

```
    @app.callback(
        Output('county-dpdn', 'options'),
        Output('county-dpdn', 'value'),
        Input('state-dpdn', 'value'),
    )
    def set_county_options(chosen_state):
        dff = df[df.State == chosen_state]
        counties_of_state = [{'label': c, 'value': c} for c in sorted(dff.County.unique())]
        values_selected = [x['value'] for x in counties_of_state]
        return counties_of_state, values_selected

    @app.callback(
        Output('radio-buttons', 'options'),
        Output('radio-buttons', 'value'),
        Input('county-dpdn', 'value'),
    )
    def set_job_options(chosen_county):
        dff = df[df.County == chosen_county] ###THIS IS LINE 255 W/ ERROR###
        job_of_county = [{'label': c, 'value': c} for c in dff.Job.unique()]
        values_selected = job_of_county[0]['value']
        return job_of_county, values_selected

    @app.callback(
        Output('graph1', 'children'),
        Input('radio-buttons', 'value'),
        Input('county-dpdn', 'value'),
        Input('state-dpdn', 'value')
    )
    def build_graph(job_selected, location_selected, state_selected):
        if isinstance(state_selected, str):
            df['State'].eq(state_selected)

        if isinstance(location_selected, str):
            df['County'].eq(location_selected)

        if isinstance(job_selected, str):
            df['Job'].eq(job_selected)

        dffgraph = df[df['State'].eq(state_selected) & df['County'].eq(location_selected) & df['Job'].eq(job_selected)]

        ###dffgraph manipulation and figure creation down here###
```

All of this works, loads the data as intended, and my graphs are great. My problem comes when trying to get this out to users without throwing errors. Errors were helpful in constructing everything but when it came time to tweak the presentation of my graphs, I silenced the errors to come back to them later using dev_tools:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False, port=5000, dev_tools_ui=False, dev_tools_props_check=False)
```

I am creating a multipage dash app which works great, but when I put this code into my main multipage app or if I remove the dev tools from the local 'app.run_server' shown above I get the following error:

```
File "/Users/Documents/pythonProject/app.py", line 255, in set_job_options
dff = df[df.County == chosen_county]
File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py", line 65, in new_method
return method(self, other)
File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 370, in wrapper
res_values = comparison_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py", line 225, in comparison_op
"Lengths must match to compare", lvalues.shape, rvalues.shape
ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (4781,), (64,))
```

The csv file used for creating my df is 4781 lines long, and 64 is the number of parishes in Louisiana, so the number make sense.

While ignoring this error has worked thus far, after weeks of trying to occasionally figure this out I would love some help with this error. Thank you!

***Edit 1***

For help with simply silencing the errors, it is best to show how my app is setup. I have a multipage Flask app, with my Dash app being called when the user is directed to it.

My dashboard.py file looks like:

```
def init_dashboard(server):
    """Create a Plotly Dash dashboard."""
    dash_app = dash.Dash(
        server=server,
        routes_pathname_prefix='/dashapp/',
        external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.FLATLY]
    )

    # Load DataFrame
    df = create_dataframe()

    and so on....

    return dash_app.server
```

The **init**.py file in my flask app that calls my dashboard.py:

```
def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    .... all the normal init stuff ....

    from .plotlydash.dashboard import init_dashboard
    app = init_dashboard(app)

    return app
```

Prior to deployment while testing my dash app as a single entity, debug=False, dev_tools_ui=False, dev_tools_props_check=False all work well to silence the dash errors. When I put my working dash app into my flask app as shown above it still works just fine, but it throws errors which are logged and sent to my email like crazy. I've tried a few different approaches to silencing only the errors from my dash app but haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: What if you try `dff = df.copy()` and then `dff = dff[dff.County == chosen_county]`. Same for the others where you are taking a slice of `df`. Not sure if that might create this error message in `plotly-dash`.

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't work. The callbacks stopped functioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit at bottom**.

The problem is you're doing this:

`dff = df[df.County == chosen_county]`

but the `==` won't work with a list, and `chosen_county` is a list. You should do

`dff = df[df.County.isin(chosen_county)]`

or require that only a single value be selected and it not be a list.

Edit:
To do this with a single value dropdown, I think the right way would be:

`dff = df[df['County'].eq(chosen_county)]`

The dropdown should not have `multi=True`, that was from my previous misunderstanding. Please let me know if this still is not working.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this didn't work. The callbacks stopped functioning.

Comment: Does it give you an error? What does the error say?

Comment: ```job_of_county = [{'label': c, 'value': c} for c in dff.Job.unique()]
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax.```. The arrow is pointing to the y in county (hard to format in the comment section).  Interestingly, the dff in ```dff = df[df.County == chosen_county]``` goes light grey when applying this .isin approach.

Comment: Does it work as `df[df['County'].isin(chosen_county)]`?

Comment: It allows the graph to function again, but it is bringing every possible job from my df. I only have jobs "A" and "B" listed in my play data above, but this is returning jobs E,F,G...Z, jobs that are not in the listed intended county.  It also gives this error: ```TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]```.  Should I change the ```values_selected = [x['value'] for x in counties_of_state]``` in my first callback to return a string?

Comment: You want the user to be able to select multiple options from the county dropdown, right? Set it to `multi=True`. That might resolve the issue with the `TypeError`, too.

Comment: No, I want them to only choose one state and one county at a time. However, I do want them to be able to choose multiple jobs from the selected county (using radioitems to populate a scheduling chart). I just tried adding multi=True and the "Job" pulldown wasn't receiving any data from the "County" pulldown. State and County were talking to each other just fine though. My apologies if this is taking up your time. I greatly appreciate the help (you seriously helped me on a previous question too).

Comment: No problem. I'm here to help. I misunderstood, and thought you wanted multiple selections. `isin` is the wrong tool in this case. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: They work together again but still give errors, although they don't include the length of possible options from the df.  I know this isn't good practice, but is there a way to silence these since everything works great from the user's perspective? ```                                                  
                if len(other) != len(self):
                raise ValueError("Lengths must be equal")```

Comment: You can pass `debug=False` to the `run_server` command. That will remove errors from the UI.

Comment: That works great when it is local, but I have this in a multi-page flask app. I'm going to edit my original for easier viewing. Thank you!!!